# Finding the dominant frequency of a time series data using fft matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series, fft, forecasting

I'm trying to determine the dominant frequency of a time series data using the fft function in matlab. my data is represented as a vector while my time scale is also a vector. Below is my sample code:

```
Fs = 10; % sampling frequency 1 kHz
t =  [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]; % time scale
x = [10,120,130,120,120,100,123,456,78,89]; % time series
plot(t,x), axis('tight'), grid('on'), title('Time series'), figure
nfft = 512; % next larger power of 2
y = fft(x,nfft); % Fast Fourier Transform
y = abs(y.^2); % raw power spectrum density
y = y(1:1+nfft/2); % half-spectrum
[v,k] = max(y); % find maximum
f_scale = (0:nfft/2)* Fs/nfft; % frequency scale
plot(f_scale, y),axis('tight'),grid('on'),title('Dominant Frequency')
fest = f_scale(k); % dominant frequency estimate
fprintf('Dominant freq.: true %f Hz, estimated %f Hznn', f, fest)
fprintf('Frequency step (resolution) = %f Hznn', f_scale(2))
```

The problem is that my dominant frequency here is 0 which am not quite sure if it is correct. Could some provide feedback on this please especially if the Fs matters alot in this case!

Comment: The data you are analyzing is very short and non-periodic. It's unlikely you will get anything useful from frequency analysis of this data.

Comment: thanks...what about the code?

Comment: Try to compose your data by summing up different sines and see if you get the frequency of the most powerful one. And mind the Nyquist frequency..

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the code, 0 frequency would indicate something like a DC signal, what does your fft plot look like? y = fft(x,nfft) should generate the frequency response. Also could be due to leakage, try setting fs to higher value and see what the response look like

Comment: Fs = 1000; % sampling frequency 1 kHz
t =  0 : 1/Fs : 0.296; % time scale
f = 100; % Hz, embedded dominant frequency
x = cos(2*pi*f*t) + randn(size(t)); % time series

Thanks..I modified the code by replacing this and now my dominant frequency is 100 which is expected. what do you mean by leakage?

Comment: Try to test your code with some simple signals, like `1+3*cos(2*x)+0.5*sin(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1) generate a signal containing many frequencies

x = 0:0.1:100;

y = 0;

for i = 1:10,

y = y + sin(2*pi*rand(1)*10*x);

end

2) Use pwelch to obtain the power sprectrum. As window fct use flattopwin. This insures, that the scalloping loos is small (the amplitude of the signal will be correct)

3) Use the scaling Eq (11) in [link]http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fhnw.ch%2Ftechnik%2Fime%2Fpublikationen%2F2012%2Fhow-to-use-the-fft-and-matlab2019s-pwelch-function-for-signal-and-noise-simulations-and-measurements&ei=V3EIVZrhHMPeOLeugbAH&usg=AFQjCNF6Fw1yrHI8EN20vzaBpJFXGjARxA&sig2=8VueptB1v3SA2Xp4A9cyYg&bvm=bv.88528373,d.ZWU&cad=rja[/link] to obtain the correct amplitude.

4) Check the amplitude: Convert the PSD into a linear spectrum --> This is not necessary. However, I often want to know the value of the amplitude. However, be aware, that pwelch calculates the rms-amplitude not the peak-amplitude. To obtain the peak-amplitude multiply by sqrt(2).

Best,  Jonas

Comment: Ok i will also try this

Answer (score 0):

If the average of your input data vector is large relative to the data elements, that represents a significant DC offset, and can show up as a dominant frequency of 0 in the FFT result.  You can subtract the average of your data vector from each element to remove this DC offset.